# How to remove one item in this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have 2 lists

```
list1 = [['abc', '123'], ['def', '456']]
list2 = ['abc','123','def','456','ghi','789']
```

How can I remove 1 element from list1 by typing only the letters or the number

For example if I type 'abc' OR '123' I want it to display

```
[['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]
```

in list2 I can make it remove the pair by the following code

```
contact = input("Type the name/number of the contact you want to remove")
if contact in list2:
    pos = list2.index(contato)
    if pos % 2 == 0:
        list2.pop(pos)
        list2.pop(pos)
    if pos % 2 != 0:
        list2.pop(pos-1)
        list2.pop(pos-1)
```

However I wouldn't be able to do that in list1 as both number and letters are together so the I guess the only way would be to transfer the new list2 to list1 but I'm not sure how I would do that

I know what I wrote is really confusing, but basically I want to transform

```
this: ['def','456','ghi','789'] into this: [['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know what I wrote is really confusing, but basically I want to transform
>
> `this: ['def','456','ghi','789'] into this: [['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]`

Use a simple list comprehension to nest the list at every two elements:

```
>>> l = ['def','456','ghi','789']
>>> l = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(l[0::2], l[1::2])]
>>> l
[['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]
>>>
```

What this does is it iterates through the list by every two elements. This only works however if the list are the same length. This would break:

```
>>> l = ['def','456','ghi','789', 'foo']
>>> l = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(l[0::2], l[1::2])]
>>> l
[['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789']]
>>>
```

The problem, is the builtin `zip()` stops at the shortest iterable. If you need to group a list that can have uneven length, use `itertools.zip_longest()`. It will fill `None` into any unmatched values:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest # izip_longest for Python 2.x users
>>> l = ['def','456','ghi','789', 'foo']
>>> l = [[i, j] for i, j in zip_longest(l[0::2], l[1::2])]
>>> l
[['def', '456'], ['ghi', '789'], ['foo', None]]
>>>
```

Comment: user seems new to python. maybe you should teach them about the tuple.

Comment: Ah! beat me to it!

Comment: it looks like they want `(name, phone)`

Comment: @anshanno Yep. That's how it always is ;)

Comment: @naomik Really? in the last part of his question he showed a **nested list**. Maybe I don't understand you though.

Comment: If something is wrong with my answer, I'd love to know so I can fix it: `404: unknown reason for down vote`

Comment: Thanks, It worked! the list length is always even so the last step wasn't needed

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
contact = input("Type the name/number of the contact you want to remove")
for i in range(len(list1)):
    pair = list1[i]
    if contact in pair:
        list1.pop(pair)
```

What this does, is loop through numbers from 0 to `len(list1)`, which are the indices for all the items in `list1`. If the item at that index contains the typed contact, pop it from `list1`.

As @leaf's answer suggests, you can also do this using list comprehension.

```
contact = input("Type the name/number of the contact you want to remove")
result = [pair for pair in list1 if contact not in pair]
```

This does basically the same thing as the code above, but in a slightly different way. The brackets `[ ... ]` indicate you're creating a new list. The expression between these brackets specifies what should go in the list.

The part that goes `for pair in list1` looks familiar, right? It's basically a `for` loop that loops over the elements in `list1`, assigning each item in turn to the `pair` variable.

But the expression we have here is slightly different, it starts with: `pair for pair in list1`. That first `pair` is an expression that specifies what you want to put in the resulting list, for each iteration of the loop. In this case, we're just putting the pair straight into the resulting list, but you can modify it here. Let's say you just wanted to put the first element of each pair in the resulting list, then you'd write:

```
result = [pair[0] for pair in list1]
```

So what's that last part about? That `if contact not in pair` part specifies that only pairs that don't include `contact` should be put into our new list. You could put any expression there, and any time that expression evaluates to `True`, the item would be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're coming to python from another language. I'm going to recommend a list of tuples for your final data, but can change that to a list of of lists if you like that better

I'll start with a function that converts your flat list in to a list of 2-element tuples, called `make_phonebook`. Then we will make a `filter_phonebook` function which takes a phonebook and an input `query`, and returns a new phonebook where entries that matched the input query are removed

```
def make_phonebook(iterable):
  z = iter(iterable)
  return [(x,y) for x,y in zip(z,z)]

def filter_phonebook(phonebook, query):
  return [(name,phone)
           for name,phone in phonebook
             if name != query and phone != query]
```

Now we can very easily work with the data

```
list2 = ['abc','123','def','456','ghi','789']
book = make_phonebook(list2)

print(filter_phonebook(book, 'abc'))
# [('def', '456'), ('ghi', '789')]

print(filter_phonebook(book, '123'))
# [('def', '456'), ('ghi', '789')]

print(filter_phonebook(book, 'def'))
# [('abc', '123'), ('ghi', '789')]
```